# Imgcache.js Init not reaching callbacks

Tags: caching, ionic2, external

I'm using `ImgCache.js` within my ionic2 project, recently I upgraded ionic from `rc.3` to `rc.5` and `ImgCache` stopped working.

While debugging, I could see that the success and error callbacks in `ImgCaches.Init()` were never called. So I debugged the `ImgCache.js`' `Init` method and was able to find that the method:

`navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota`

Is only calling any callback when the `Quota` data is bigger than the previous amount (or after I cleaned the cache/cookies), which will ask the user permission to store files in his device.

I tested in `canary` (version `58.0.2989.0 canary (64-bit)`) but this didn't work either.

P.s.: The problematic code is here: https://github.com/chrisben/imgcache.js/blob/master/js/imgcache.js#L622

P.s.2: It's only happening when I set a breakpoint before `ImgCache.init()`

Comment: *"It's only happening when I set a breakpoint before ImgCache.init()"* So when removing the breakpoint your problem is resolved? Then I believe that this is only a development issue but not for production, is it?

Comment: Yes, I didn't delete the question because other people might get the same error.

Comment: Aah okay, please answer your question :) looks unanswered now so people will come and look to find a solution for you

Answer (score 0):

After a couple hours of debugging, I discovered the problem was actually the debugging. The problem only occured when I set a `debugger` before `ImgCache.init()`